# Supporting International Billing Addresses, when they are a small % of user base

Tags: forms, e-commerce, internationalisation

Our site is expanding internationally. During our checkout process, we ask customers to give us billing information such as Address, City, State, & Zip Code. This is used both for fraud prevention and for customer analytics. While I would love to eliminate these fields since we aren't shipping anything, business conditions exist where we need to keep collecting this info.

The kicker to all of this is that we are strong proponents of minimizing clicks to purchase, and the USA/Canada will likely remain 90% of our business for the foreseeable future.

Has anyone seen any excellent international address forms out there in the wild? I have read this excellent article [International Address Fields in Web Forms](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2008/06/international-address-fields-in-web-forms.php) but was wondering if there were any studies a bit more up-to-date than this.

Comment: Not a study, but [this list](http://bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats.html) or formats for international addresses, very exhaustive, although not complete may help you

Comment: Is your intention that everybody should use the same set of fields, regardless of country, and that you want to make as little impact as possible on the customer journey for US/Canada residents? Or is the idea that the address section should switch to international format when the customer informs the page that he/she lives outside US/Canada?

Answer (score 1):

Ask for country first. US and Canada can be on top of your drop list (not alphabetically). 
If US or Canada are selected, present the address fields optimized for these countries (the only difference is zip/postal code... even phone is +1 ).
If other counties are selected, you can have a different, more generic, set of fields. 
But optimize for US/CA which represents 90% of your business.